# App crashing caused by onClick View

Tags: javascript, android, browser, webview, onclick

I'm making a WebView browser and I've made a button that will make the browser reload but it makes it crash, I'm relatively new to Android coding so i apologize if the question is noob

```
class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    public void refreshButtonClicked(View view)
    {
        ourBrow.reload();
    }
    public void goButtonClicked(View view)
    {
         String theWebsite = Url.getText().toString();
         if(theWebsite != null)
          ourBrow.loadUrl(theWebsite);
    }

}
```

And heres the XML part with the button

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/bGo"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etURL"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/go"
        android:onClick="goButtonClicked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bRefresh"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etURL"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/reload"
        android:onClick="refreshButtonClicked" />
```

Comment: You want me to read your log which is 7015 lines? just post the error  log where you get the error

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method refreshButtonClicked(View) in the activity class com.browser.tssomas.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'bRefresh'

Comment: there is some error in your refresh method . paste your main activity where bRefresh is initialized

Comment: Its in the top half of the code I pasted in?

Comment: upload the main activity class code on mediafire let me check

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/a4hazjxwot3j5z9/MainActivity.java

Comment: ^Thats the MainActivity, thanks by the way :)

Comment: i have done changes to your code try it now http://www.mediafire.com/view/z5kc3fk7p61n6z3/ThomasTrythis.txt

Comment: Yes! It works perfectly, thank you so much I really appreciate it. Is there anything I can do, like give you good feedback on your profile or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a separate  **class myWebClient extends WebViewClient**

just put these methods in your **MainActivity** itself

```
 public void refreshButtonClicked(View view)
{
    ourBrow.reload();
}

public void goButtonClicked(View view)
{
     String theWebsite = Url.getText().toString();
     if(theWebsite != null)
      ourBrow.loadUrl(theWebsite);
}
```